# Selenium and Python: what is the correct way to define WebElement as property

Tags: python, selenium

Please see this classes:

**Browser**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains as actions


class Browser:

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\chromedriver.exe")
webDriverWait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
action = actions(driver)

def goto(self, url):
    Browser.driver.maximize_window()
    Browser.driver.get(url)
```

**HomePage**

```
from seleniumbase.Browser import Browser
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from seleniumbase.BaseActions import BaseActions


class HomePage:
    url = "myURL"

    def __init__(self):
        self.usernametextbox = Browser.webDriverWait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "login_email")))
        self.passwordtextbox = Browser.webDriverWait.until(
            ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr[id=mockpass] input")))
        self.loginbutton = Browser.webDriverWait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "login")))

    def getusernametextbox(self):
        return self.usernametextbox

    def getpasswordtextbox(self):
        return self.passwordtextbox

    def getloginbutton(self):
        return self.loginbutton

    def login(self):
        self.getusernametextbox().send_keys("myuser@gmail.com")
        self.getpasswordtextbox().send_keys("12345678")
        self.getloginbutton().click()
```

As you can see i define my `WebElements` as  methosds.

Is it the write way to do that or there is better way to do that ?

Is it the write way to do that or there is better way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not define each element inside `__init__`, try to use below instead:

```
@property
def getusernametextbox(self):
    return Browser.webDriverWait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "login_email")))

@property
def getpasswordtextbox(self):
    return Browser.webDriverWait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr[id=mockpass] input")))

@property
def getloginbutton(self):
    return Browser.webDriverWait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "login")))

def login(self):
        self.getusernametextbox.send_keys("myuser@gmail.com")
        self.getpasswordtextbox.send_keys("12345678")
        self.getloginbutton.click()
```

Comment: And what about the __init__ ? i can remove it ?

Comment: In case your HomePage instance should be created without arguments